# How can I create the water-like blur effect in Chameleon Run using SpriteKit and Unity?

Tags: unity, spritekit, swift, effects, blur

As the character in [Chameleon Run](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrIAedC-wJY) runs, a water-like blur effect is created. I would really appreciate some guidelines on how I could create this effect in SpriteKit and Unity. Please see the image below.

[image]

Comment: @Bálint just updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like this could be done with a [TrailRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html). This leaves a ribbon of 3D geometry behind a moving object, onto which we can assign a material to control the way it renders.

We can use a custom shader incorporating a [GrabPass to take a snapshot of the frame buffer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-GrabPass.html), sampling it with a distortion offset, to get a refractive watery look:

```
Shader "Unlit/DistortionTrail"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Intensity ("Intensity", Range(-1, 1)) = 1
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent"}
        LOD 100

        GrabPass {"_Refract"}

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;              
                float4 projected : TEXCOORD1;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _Refract;         
            float2 _Refract_TexelSize;

            float _Intensity;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                o.projected = o.vertex;

            // Some video settings flip the captured image - flip it back.
            #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                o.projected.y *= sign(_Refract_TexelSize.y);
            #endif

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // Convert interpolated vertex position in device coordinates
                // into a texture coordinate in the range 0...1
                float2 screenUV = (i.projected.xy / i.projected.w) * 0.5f + 0.5f;

                // Ripple the distortion across the width of the trail.
                // (squaring y makes the ripples look a bit less rigid/uniform)
                float distortion = sin(i.uv.y * i.uv.y * 3.141592653589f * 5.0f);

                // Fade the distortion along the length of the trail.
                distortion *= 1.0f - i.uv.x;

                // Control max distortion using material parameter.
                distortion *= _Intensity;

                // Offset our lookup coordinates using the distortion.
                screenUV += distortion * float2(0.5, 1);

                // Sample the captured snapshot of the frame.
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_Refract, screenUV);

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of this in motion:

[image]